# How to create Pagination For Bootstrap "list-group-item"?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am creating a Bootstrap **"list-group-item"** dynamically when page loads, based on number of results, items will be populate in Bootstrap list-group-item. But the result may have too much of items when i populate, so i need to create a Pagination for my Bootstrap list-group-item by breaking items and show max 10 items per page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>List Group With Custom Content</h2>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">First List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">List Group Item Text</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Second List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">List Group Item Text</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Third List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">List Group Item Text</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">fourth List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">List Group Item Text</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">fifth List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">List Group Item Text</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">sixth List Group Item Heading</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">List Group Item Text</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have got this small solution in Github try this out it might be helpful
https://gist.github.com/rxtur/6c29e2b0d81bac2578ca

Comment: Thank you this answer is use full but not meeting my need. thank you for your help.